# Predicted classification probability from a tree node in trained sklearn DecisionTreeClassifier

Tags: python, scikit-learn, decision-tree

I have fit an instance of DecisionTreeClassifier and I am trying to extract prediction probabilities for each node.  I need this in order to create custom decision tree visualization similar to what is shown below.

I can export features and thresholds for each node.

```
dtc.tree_.feature
Out[72]: array([93, 36, 92, 51, 84, -2, 20, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2,  6, -2, -2])

dtc.tree_.threshold
Out[73]: 
array([ 50.5       ,   0.5       ,  85.50991821,   0.5       ,
         5.5       ,  -2.        ,   0.5       ,  -2.        ,
        -2.        ,  -2.        ,  -2.        ,  -2.        ,
         0.5       ,  -2.        ,  -2.        ])
```

Ideally I would export prediction probabilities for each node using something similar to this.

```
dtc.tree_.probability
Out[xx]:
array([0.50, 0.42, 0.21, 0.45, 0.62, ....])
```

Is this possible?

[image]

Comment: Maybe this can help: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/tree/plot_unveil_tree_structure.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-tree-plot-unveil-tree-structure-py

Comment: That example helped me find the feature and threshold values, but I don't see a way to extract probabilities for each node other than artificially creating a sample based on each decision path.  And that would only get me terminal nodes :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I discovered that values is the count of samples that fall in each class and my "prediction probability" can be considered the proportion of samples that fall in a given class.  Thus I can calculate it using the following:

```
samples = dtc.tree_.n_node_samples
class1_positives = dtc.tree_.value[:,0,1]
probs = (class1_positives/samples).tolist()
```

Comment: Hi! I was faced a problem of prediction probability to be positive in class 'balanced' DecisionTreeClassifier. I can't understand how it is calculated in this "mode" (in predict_proba() method)

Comment: Hi I hope it is not too late but, in the "balanced" case, ( see https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html , class_weight parameter)   the way you calculate the probs is the same values / sum(values) (see each node chart tree) but values are samples weighted;  each samples is weighted by 1/Prob(y==class)  (example=  1/Prob(y==1) and 1/Prob(y==0) in binary classification)